# Can you create AWS Cognito App Client Programmatically? (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have an existing AWS Cognito user pool and existing app clients. Is it possible for me to add app clients programmatically using SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All of your answers can be found here.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#createUserPoolClient-property

Comment: what I mean is app_client. Is it possible for me to generate client_id and client_secret

Comment: the docs linked above is for creating an app_client. The only mandatory fields are `UserPoolId` and `ClientName`. It will return you the `ClientId`. If you sent `GenerateSecret: true` in the call.it will return a `ClientSecret`